# Cannot launch any java webstart applet

Tags: java, applet, jvm, java-web-start, jnlp

Every time I try to launch a JNLP file, I get the error "Could not start the Java Virtual Machine". I've tried decreasing/increasing the max memory heap size and launching the application through the cmd with no success.
I have 8 GB of RAM and Java is permitted to use 5GB. Sorry if this is in the wrong place but I'm fairly desperate to get it working.
Thanks.

Comment: So [this JNLP based applet](http://pscode.org/gifanim/#applet) fails on that box?

Comment: Can you share the JNLP file contents?  If you are running 32 bit Java, then it doesn't matter that you have 5GB - your process can only get 2GB at max(but generally only can set max to 1.2G before the VM won't start.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I forgot to come back to this post. I played around with some general Java memory settings and I can open them now. I've got 64 bit Java btw.